# FirebaseAppError: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I follow this link https://pragli.com/blog/how-to-authenticate-with-google-in-electron/ to authenticate-with-google-in-electron.
here are my codes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "podium-***.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://podium-***.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "podium-***",
  storageBucket: "podium-***.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "1:***:web:***",
  measurementId: "G-***"
};

admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

router.post('/createCustomToken', async (req, res) => {
  try {


    // const query = request.query
    const idToken = req.body.idToken;
    // console.log(idToken);
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
      .then(function (decodedToken) {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        console.log(uid);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
    // console.log(decodedToken);
    const uid = decodedToken.uid

    const authToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)

    console.log('Authentication token', authToken)

    // await admin.database().ref(`ot-auth-codes/${oneTimeCode}`).set(authToken)

    res.status(200).json({
      token: authToken
    })

  } catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

console error:

> FirebaseAppError: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET
> at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (E:\User\Documents\Work\Angular-demo\podium-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:42:28)
> at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (E:\User\Documents\Work\Angular-demo\podium-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:88:28)
> at new FirebaseAppError (E:\User\Documents\Work\Angular-demo\podium-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:123:28)
> at E:\User\Documents\Work\Angular-demo\podium-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\api-request.js:209:19
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
> errorInfo: {
> code: 'app/network-error',
> message: 'Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET'
> },
> codePrefix: 'app'
> }

any helps? thanks:)